# In Xcode, where is the compiled .app file? (macOS application)

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode10

On iOS I did not bother with that info, because you run the app on the device or simulator.

This is macOS application.

I want to launch my app **without** Xcode. Where is the app file location?

I'm using Xcode 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is in the `Products` group in `Xcode`.

If you want to know the actual location in the file system:

`Right click > Show in Finder`:

[image: Right click > Show in Finder]

Answer (score 3):

In case you are looking for the folder of compiled programs:
By default it is present in :

- Macintosh HD >
- Users > (user name) >
- Library >
- Developer >
- Xcode >
- DerivedData

DerivedData is the folder where all the compiled programs are kept. You need to access the:
(desired) folder > Build > Products > Debug 
to access the executable app.

For easy access I'll suggest to make Alias of the DerivedData folder onto desktop.

Answer (score 2):

After the build, you can find it under Products, you can find it in the `Project navigator` writing `.app` (it is located on disk in the derived data folder).

[image]